# Android: Open a camera that stays open

Tags: android, camera

I want to open a camera programmatically that stays open, rather than take one picture and be done. I don't have an exact package that I necessarily want to open. How can I do this?

Comment: You want the camera to remain open for what reason? Do you want the camera to return multiple images? Please state the purpose..

Comment: I just want to launch a camera from my app. That's it. Once I launch the camera, it doesn't interact with my app in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Don't forget to add this to manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

Comment: That returns an image. I just want to launch the camera.

Comment: Change `CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST` to `0`

Comment: Still returns after one picture is taken. I want the camera to stay open.

Answer (score 0):

From your activity...

```
final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

The list contains the ResolveInfo (which has ActivityInfo, and as such, package names) of any application that can handle the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. You can then get an intent to start one of these applications by calling

getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkg);

Where pkg is the string package name retrieved from the ResolveInfo.